# Prove that a set of $n+1$ polynomials is linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra

let $ \left \{ p_0,p_1,...,p_n \right \}\subseteq F[x]{_\leq {_n}} \;$ be a set of polynomials such that $\deg(p_i) = i \; \forall \; n\leq i\leq 0 $

It is quite intuitive why this set is linearly independent - however, how can I justify this in a formal way?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Use the isomorphism $\;F[X]_{\le n}\simeq F^{n+1}$, i.e. identify polynomials with the sequence of their coefficients (as column vectors) and calculate the determinant of the resulting matrix. It is an upper triangular determinant. What do you have on the diagonal?

Answer (score 0):

If $\sum_ia_ip_i=0$ and $p_i$ has $x^i$ coefficient $c_i$, the $x^n$ coefficient gives $a_nc_n=0$, so $c_n\ne0\implies a_n=0$, and the other coefficients then follow by backwards induction.